# Where and how is stored the value of "Use default value" checkboxes in Magento 2 database?

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2, product-attribute, database-schema

On my Magento 2 website, I have multiple stores.

On the product page of each store, description is not shown because it's defined globally and each product has the "Use default value" checkbox unchecked for each store.

What I'm attempting to do is changing the value of those checkboxes all at once from the database, but i can't find where and how it's stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those checkboxes are form fields only and not being persistet in the database. They show if an attributes values is going to be saved in the current store. Magento will evaluate them when saving the product. When checked magento will delete the attributes value for the current store and in the frontend will fallback to its value of the default store.

I can be wrong, but your products probably really have empty description values saved for each store other than default store in the product entity tables. Thus, you actually want to find and delete those empty product descriptions.

Search for those descriptions eg. with (adapt to your needs):

```
SELECT d.* FROM catalog_product_entity_text AS d
INNER JOIN eav_attribute AS a ON a.attribute_id = d.attribute_id
WHERE a.attribute_code="description" AND d.store_id > 0 AND TRIM(value) = '';
```